# how to add array elements in one array according to condition in other array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays say one is string array and the other is int array
string array has---> "11","11","11","11","12","12" elements and the int array has 1,2,3,4,5,6 respectively.

I want result two arrays containing string array--->"11","12"
and int array---->10,11

If the string array has duplicate elements, the other array containing that respective index value must be added .For example "11" is in 1st,2nd,3rd,4th index So its corresponding value must sum of all those elements in other array.Can it be done?

I have written some code but unable to do it..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var newchartValues = ["","","","","","",""];
            //var newdates = dates.Split(',');
            //string[] newchartarray = newchartValues;            
            //string[] newdatearray = newdates;
            int[] newchartValues = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            string[] newdates = new string[] { "11", "11","11","12","12","12" };
            int[] intarray = new int[newchartValues.Length];
            List<int> resultsumarray = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < newchartValues.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                intarray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(newchartValues[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < newdates.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < intarray.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (newdates[i] == newdates[i + 1])
                    {
                        intarray[j] += intarray[j + 1];
                        resultsumarray.Add(intarray[j]);
                    }
                }
                resultsumarray.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are the two separate arrays a hard requirement in your situation, or can you declare a class/struct that stores the string along with the int and then only have *one* array whose elements are instances of that class/struct?

Comment: Please read the explanation

Comment: As for your explanation, as far as I understood, your string array should be split into two groups: *11, 11, 11, 11* and *12, 12* (BTW, this is different in your code). The corresponding elements of the int array are *1, 2, 3, 4* and *5, 6*. The sums of these two latter groups are *10* and *11*.

Comment: Yeah exactly @O.R.Mapper

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Why are the sums of `1+2+3` and `4+5+6` 10 and 11?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Because, as I implied in my comment, the code deviates from the description. It makes more sense in the description, as there, it's the sums of `1+2+3+4` and `5+6`. Note that in the example in the description, there is four times *11* and only twice *12*, while it's three and three times in the code.

Comment: Oh  i see. I have taken his requirement from the text and the sample from his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get what you need, but I think I fixed your code, result will contain 10 and 11 in this example:

```
int[] newchartValues = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
string[] newdates = new string[] { "11", "11", "11", "11", "12", "12" };

List<int> result = new List<int>();
if (newdates.Length == 0)
    return;
string last = newdates[0];
int cursum = newchartValues[0];
for (var i = 1; i <= newdates.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == newdates.Length || newdates[i] != last)
    {
        result.Add(cursum);
        if (i == newdates.Length)
            break;
        last = newdates[i];
        cursum = 0;
    }
    cursum += newchartValues[i];
}
```

Comment: The result is conataining 6 and 15 btw..You said its containing 10 and 11

Comment: No. If you copy and paste my code exactly, the result will be 10 and 11. If you don't copy my entire code, and use newdates from your question (which is different, 11,11,11,12,12,12), then it will contain 6 and 15.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that should do what you want:

```
List<int> resultsumarray =  newdates
    .Select((str, index) => new{ str, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.str)
    .Select(xg => xg.Sum(x => newchartValues[x.index]))
    .ToList();
```

Result is a `List<int>` with two number: 6, 15

Comment: I am convinced the OP will be able to copy and paste this, but I am not convinced the OP will know why his or her code did not work and why this code does, without any further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
int[] newchartValues = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int[] newdates = new int[] { 11, 11,11,12,12,12 };
var pairs = Enumerable.Zip(newdates, newchartValues, (x, y) => new { x, y })
      .GroupBy(z => z.x)
      .Select(g => new { k = g.Key, s = g.Sum(z => z.y) })
      .ToList();
var distinctDates = pairs.Select(p => p.k).ToArray();
var sums = pairs.Select(p => p.s).ToArray();
```

Comment: The result must contain the sum of correspoding duplicates ie I have "11","11","11","11" and corresponding values are 1,2,3,4 and similarly "12","12" and 5,6 So the sum must be 1+2+3+4 and 5+6 ..btw thanx